# Regex to format paragraphs contained in txt file to separate strings

Tags: node.js, regex

I've got a txt file with 10,000+ short "paragraphs", i've been using the find and replace feature in vscode to try and match each paragraph but if there's a more effective method in javascript, I'm interested.

Essentially I want to place each paragraph which is seperated by empty lines between `""`, to make them usable strings. Typically the nature of these "paragraphs" are not really paragraphs in the context of language. They were actually just objects that I isolated away from an object list that had multiple groups and categories. But they have to be treated like paragraphs because some remaining cases are suppose to be contained inside an object group, so therefore i'd like to capture any grouping of text lines in a single string rather then separate strings per line.

Here's a sample of the txt file.

```
Description: Corsican




Description: Cree





Description: Czech





Description: Church Slavic
Description: Church Slavonic
Description: Old Bulgarian
Description: Old Church Slavonic
Description: Old Slavonic




Description: Chuvash




Description: Welsh





Description: Danish





Description: German





Description: Dhivehi
Description: Divehi
Description: Maldivian





Description: Dzongkha





Description: Ewe




Description: Modern Greek (1453-)





Description: English





Description: Esperanto





Description: Spanish
Description: Castilian





Description: Estonian






Description: Basque





Description: Persian
```

The spacing is inconsistent because the other contents from the object list were simply removed. I know vscode's find and replace can support multi line regex, so perhaps that could be used. Or maybe the job could be done in pure javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No, so you see i'm trying to not separate every text line into individual strings. I'm trying to place every GROUP of text lines into ONE string. Every group of text lines should be considered one string. And those groups are defined by the spacing between them.

Comment: Okay, i'm a little lost on what you're referring to. Can you show an example?

Comment: `"Description: Cree"` `"Description: Czech"` `"Description: Church Slavic Description: Church Slavonic Description: Old Bulgarian Description: Old Church Slavonic Description: Old Slavonic"` `"Description: Chuvash"` `"Description: Welsh"` `"Description: Danish"` `"Description: German"` `"Description: Dhivehi Description: Divehi Description: Maldivian"` `"Description: Dzongkha"` `"Description: Ewe"` `"Description: Modern Greek (1453-)"` `"Description: English"` `"Description: Esperanto"` `"Description: Spanish"` `"Description: Castilian"`...ect. That is the desired result.

Comment: Every group of text lines.

Comment: The console returns every Description next to each other. like this `Description: CreeDescription: Czech` There's no indication in the console that the strings are separating by each group. It would be more usable if we push each string into an array. Looks mostly good though.

Comment: Oh lol. I have no clue what happened. The first time I ran the code, it was just one single string. Now it's all separated correctly. That was strange? Anyway, this is great! Thanks for your help, post it as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex below for the mentioned purpose:

```
^(?:[\w:\-() ]+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regular expression:**

> **^** - Starting delimiter denoting the start of the test string.
>
> **?:** - Represents **non-capturing** group.
>
> **[\w:-() ]** - Represents the [**character class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) along with **-**, **(**, **)** and **space** to be included. You can include other symbols although according to your requirement.
>
> **+** - represents a quantifier which match the occurrence **one or more times**.
>
> **$** - Ending delimiter denoting the end of the test string.

You can see the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/aVVWFn/3)

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
const myRegexp = /^(?:[\w:\-() ]+)$/gm;
const myString = `Description: Corsican




Description: Cree





Description: Czech





Description: Church Slavic
Description: Church Slavonic
Description: Old Bulgarian
Description: Old Church Slavonic
Description: Old Slavonic




Description: Chuvash




Description: Welsh





Description: Danish





Description: German





Description: Dhivehi
Description: Divehi
Description: Maldivian





Description: Dzongkha





Description: Ewe




Description: Modern Greek (1453-)





Description: English





Description: Esperanto





Description: Spanish
Description: Castilian





Description: Estonian






Description: Basque





Description: Persian`;
let resultString = "";

let match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  resultString = resultString.concat("\"" + match + "\" ");
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Tell me if you see the difference. `"Description: Cree" "Description: Czech" "Description: Church Slavic Description: Church Slavonic Description: Old Bulgarian Description: Old Church Slavonic Description: Old Slavonic" "Description: Chuvash" "Description: Welsh" "Description: Danish" "Description: German" "Description: Dhivehi Description: Divehi Description: Maldivian" "Description: Dzongkha" "Description: Ewe" "Description: Modern Greek (1453-)" "Description: English" "Description: Esperanto" "Description: Spanish" "Description: Castilian"`

Comment: Here's a more specific comparison. Yours `"Description: Church Slavic" "Description: Church Slavonic" "Description: Old Bulgarian" "Description: Old Church Slavonic" ` Desired result. `"Description: Church Slavic Description: Church Slavonic Description: Old Bulgarian Description: Old Church Slavonic Description: Old Slavonic"` Look where the string starts and ends. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you know `javascript`, `regex` and the code which I shared, you can easily tweak it to suit your further requirements.

Comment: I posted this question to solve this issue. I didn't post it to place lines of text in strings. That's easy. The title is referring to paragraphs of multiple lines of text. Your example is separating each line into separate strings. So therefore did not solve the issue asked.

Comment: You can do it by separating the strings further on the basis of multiple `/n` i. e. Newlines character. **Logic**: if more than 1 `/n` put the `"" ` else don't

Comment: Okay i'll give it a shot and see how it goes